# Date in JSON / Highcharts

Tags: c#, json

I have an problem with the plot datetime in a graphic using an JSON object and Highcharts pluguin.

My code is organized:

My Server side send an JSON object to my client side as soon:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult DadosAtendimentosParticularesPorDentistas()
    {

        DateTime DataAtual = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime InicioMes = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

        var _listaProducao = _session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT DATA_ATENDIMENTO, VALOR FROM T_LANCAMENTO_PRODUCAO_PARTICULAR " +
                                                   "WHERE DATA_ATENDIMENTO BETWEEN :INICIO AND :FIM")
                                   .SetParameter("INICIO", InicioMes.AddMonths(-3))
                                   .SetParameter("FIM", DataAtual)
                                   .List();



        return Json(_listaProducao, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My client side receive an JSON object and make the following treatment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function producaoDentista(data) {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    $('#testegrafico').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'spline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Grafico de Faturamento',
            x: -20
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Amostragem de Convenio e Particular',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
            categories: Date,
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 5,
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                month: '%b %e, %Y',
                year: '%Y'
            }

            //dateTimeLabelFormats: {
            //    month: '%b %e, %Y',
            //    year: '%Y'
            //}
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Valor em R$'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }],
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
        },
        series: [{

            name: 'Atendimento Particular',
            data: data
            //name: 'Atendimento Particular',
            //data: data,
            //tooltip: {
            //    pointFormat: 'R$:{point.y:.2f}',
            //}
        //}, {
        //    name: 'Atendimento Convênio',
        //    data: [2.0, 3.1, 10, 40.59, 100, 200, 500, 10, 500,11, 33]
        ,}]
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GraficoAtendimento/DadosAtendimentosParticularesPorDentistas',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            producaoDentista(data)
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

My JSON is composed for following data:

[["/Date(1418223600000)/",80],["/Date(1415631600000)/",10], ["/Date(1415804400000)/",40],["/Date(1420077600000)/",8],["/Date(1420164000000)/",10],["/Date(1420164000000)/",30],["/Date(1420164000000)/",140],["/Date(1420164000000)/",10],["/Date(1420423200000)/",560]]

The dates on the chart, are being displayed like this: /Date(1418223600000)

How to solved this problem?

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the JSON transfer format for your date from .NET is not easily understood by JavaScript and needs to be converted to an integer timestamp for HighCharts to work with it. 
You can address this on the server side or the client side, but to do so on the client side you need to either convert the data before sending it to HighCharts or supply HighCharts with a format function to do the conversion.

**Convert the data to integer before charting**

Here you massage your data before handing it to HighCharts by parsing all of the date strings that .NET gives you into timestamp integers. This allows for HighCharts to use the timestamps for formatting.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function parseJsonDateToTimeStamp(value) {
        return parseInt(value.substr(6), 10); // The 6 is for trimming '/Date('
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'GraficoAtendimento/DadosAtendimentosParticularesPorDentistas',
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            // Iterate data and convert all date strings to integers using
            // the parseJsonDateToTimeStamp function above.
            // 
            // Without knowing the JSON structure I cannot show code to do this, but it
            // should be done before calling producaoDentista()
            //

            producaoDentista(data)
        }
    });
});
```

This function trims the first part of the string you get from .NET off and converts the timestamp portion to an integer to pass to a Date() constructor. You should run this function against each date value in the JSON you receive when it is first received, but before you hand the data to HighCharts for rendering.

**Adjust HighCharts config to format on the fly**

Here you modify the HighCharts config to supply it with a formatter function on the xAxis that will convert your values at runtime. This is a bit cleaner of a solution, but you lose the normal ability to format the dates with `dateTimeLabelFormats` and have to use `HighCharts.dataFormat()` manually.

```
$('#testegrafico').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Grafico de Faturamento',
        x: -20
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Amostragem de Convenio e Particular',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "datetime",
        categories: Date,
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        maxZoom: 5,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {

                // Parse the date string to an integer and format it
                return HighCharts.dateFormat('%b, %e, %Y', parseInt(this.value.substr(6), 10));
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Valor em R$'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }],
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
    },
    series: [{

        name: 'Atendimento Particular',
        data: data
        //name: 'Atendimento Particular',
        //data: data,
        //tooltip: {
        //    pointFormat: 'R$:{point.y:.2f}',
        //}
    //}, {
    //    name: 'Atendimento Convênio',
    //    data: [2.0, 3.1, 10, 40.59, 100, 200, 500, 10, 500,11, 33]
    ,}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a adapter

```
public class JsonAdapter : JsonResult
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <para></para>
    /// </summary>
    private const string _dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm:ss";

    /// <summary>
    /// <para></para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))
        {
            response.ContentType = ContentType;
        }
        else
        {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
        if (ContentEncoding != null)
        {
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        }
        if (Data != null)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            serializer.RegisterConverters(new JavaScriptConverter[] { new DateTimeJavaScriptConverter() });

            response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
        }
    }
}

public class DateTimeJavaScriptConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().ConvertToType(dictionary, type);
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (!(obj is DateTime)) return null;
        DateTime data = (DateTime)obj;
        return new DateString(data == DateTime.MinValue || data == DateTime.MaxValue ? string.Empty : data.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm:ss"));
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new[] { typeof(DateTime) }; }
    }

    private class DateString : Uri, IDictionary<string, object>
    {
        public DateString(string str) : base(str, UriKind.Relative)
        {
        }

        void IDictionary<string, object>.Add(string key, object value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        bool IDictionary<string, object>.ContainsKey(string key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        ICollection<string> IDictionary<string, object>.Keys
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        bool IDictionary<string, object>.Remove(string key)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        bool IDictionary<string, object>.TryGetValue(string key, out object value)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        ICollection<object> IDictionary<string, object>.Values
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        object IDictionary<string, object>.this[string key]
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Clear()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        void ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, object>[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        int ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Count
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.IsReadOnly
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
return JsonAdapter(_listaProducao, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```